# When is the "t" pronounced in won’t, don’t, can’t?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, speech, contractions, contraction-vs-full-form

I am a speaker of Canadian English. I have noticed that when people pronounce won’t, don’t, and can’t, often when speaking normally, they don’t release the “t”, as in connected speech. The standard pronunciation for these words includes the “t” sound, so when I see them in dictionaries, the IPA always lists them with the “t”, for example won’t (woʊnt), don’t (doʊnt), and can’t (kɑnt).

So my question is, why is my own pronunciation inconsistent? Why do I sometimes say it one way, and not the other way? There are some factors that I have personally noticed:

1. When I want to articulate words clearly, I hear myself release the “t”
2. When I repeat myself for emphasis.
3. Sometimes I just unconsciously release the “t” sound for no reason other than it happening at the moment.

Any other ideas? I know that pronunciation is a variable thing, so I wonder if anyone else has any ideas as to why we sometimes say the t and sometimes leave it out. Is it wrong to pronounce the “t”?

Comment: In general, casual speech tends to drift toward the “laziest” pronunciation that is still decipherable.

Comment: It makes sense but why is it sometimes inconsistent?

Comment: Because it’s people we’re talking about.

Comment: Right on, Jim! Language is physical habits and habits are not consistent at the millisecond level. Everybody's pronunciation varies widely and constantly. And that's just one person. Think about speech groups and you get into statistics very fast. Just as fast as unnecessary consonant clusters get simplified.

Comment: Thanks John and Jim! I teach ESL and I guess I'm a bit of a newbie to different pronunciations, which is why I asked. :) In the ESL community there is often a tendency to say there is only one right way, when in fact there is no silver bullet.

Comment: The main thing to know is this. There are three main possibilities a) the /t/ is realised by a glottal stop (by far the most common) b) the /t/ is elided completely (also very common) and 3) the /t/ is realised as a [t] (far less common than the other two, but still not uncommon). Any speaker may use any of the three major types of realisation freely switching between them. They may be influenced by a host of different factors. If you're an ESL teacher, then what your students need to know is that listening for a [t] to discern a negative is a waste of time ...

Comment: ... There may be no  /t/ at all! They need to listen for the additional stressed syllable in the negative version and also be able to recognise the strong and weak forms of the auxiliary concerned. (The strong form will be used in the negative contraction - or, indeed the negative contraction may have its own strong form).

Comment: Yes I taught them the weak and strong forms instead.

Comment: Parhaps depends on what follows.  "Don't talk" may have only one *t* sound.  But "Don't eat" should have the *t* fully pronounced.

Comment: @Araucaria-Him My own (now deleted) answer was written when I didn't know anything about phonetics (not that I know much now). Normally I'd just copy your comment and post it as a community wiki, but I think it's worth noting that before a vowel the /nt/ in "can't" can also (at least when I pronounce it) become a nasal flap [ɾ̃] in AmE, like the /nt/ in "center."